# Is "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes" (2014) explicitly based on Egyptian mythology?

Tags: dawn-of-the-planet-of-the-apes

I recently watched [Dawn of the Planet of the Apes (2014)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_of_the_Planet_of_the_Apes). I noticed the following archetypal storyline running through the movie, when abstracted to a very high level:

1. The wise king (Caesar) reigns as the natural leader over the kingdom he has established.
2. He becomes complacent (he trusts all apes unconditionally) and is "killed" (shot and left for dead) by one of his closest brethren (Koba), who is an evil warmonger that sows chaos.
3. The king's son (Blue Eyes) pays close attention, realises that the throne was unrightfully usurped, and mounts a resistance.
4. The king is restored in his power.

This seems to resemble the Egyptian [Osiris myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osiris_myth)  a lot:

1. The wise king (Osiris) reigns over Egypt.
2. He becomes complacent and is killed by his brother (Set), who is an evil warmonger that sows chaos.
3. The king's son (Horus), notorious for his eye(s), rises up to fight the usurper.
4. The king's son takes the throne to become the new king.

The only real difference between the two arcs is who fights and is instituted as the new king: in the movie, this is the old king, whilst in the myth, it is the heir.

However, I cannot find any online source where it is confirmed that this very parallel storyline was intended by the writers. The above parallelism seems too strong to be coincidental, and reminds us of how strikingly parallel *The Matrix (1999)* movie resembles Plato's cave allegory.

Is there stronger evidence to support that Dawn of the Planet of the Apes was based on the Osiris myth?

---

**Edit:** It seems that people are really eager to downvote this question as quackery, writing off the movie's plot as a generic good-vs-evil story. Thanks for the warm welcome, but I don't think we should be so quick to dismiss explicit ties to mythology.

I just watched the final instalment of the series ([War for the Planet of the Apes (2017)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_for_the_Planet_of_the_Apes)), and it is rife with mythological references, from the crucifixion and torture of the saviour (Caesar) on the cross (inspired by the New Testament, [which others have noticed](https://www.reddit.com/r/PlanetOfTheApes/comments/929v3r/puzzling_out_the_jesus_imagery_in_war/)), to the journey through the desert towards [the promised land](https://planetoftheapes.fandom.com/wiki/Oasis) (inspired by the Old Testament, specifically the story of Moses, Exodus). These are clearly not generic tropes. You can write it off as "just another war movie", but that's clearly too cynical.

Comment: Seems similar to the plot of Hamlet too, no?  Why pick that particular source?

Comment: Seems similar to *any* story where the bad and jealous #2 wants to take over the good #1. Then add redemption or taking back what's owned.

Comment: Or *The Lion King* perhaps?

Comment: @DavidW I never got to Shakespeare, so I don't know the story of Hamlet. I'll check it out.

Comment: @OldPadawan I'd say the father-son dynamic is quite unique. It's not just "battle of good and evil". It's specifically a king who is usurped by a companion and avenged by his son. Hamlet seems to have this dynamic too at a glance, although from what I've just read, Hamlet seems to have more twists and turns. I'd say it's harder to compare *Dawn of the Planet of the Apes* with Hamlet than with the Osiris myth (but all the downvoters seem to disagree, so I guess it's pointless to go deeper).

Comment: @Mew possibly because Hamlet is arguably the greatest play in the English language and Dawn of the Planet of the Apes is the summer remake of a 1973 movie.

Answer (score 2):

### You can’t prove a negative, but no

The most obvious inspiration is *[Battle for the Planet of the Apes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069768/?ref_=ext_shr_lnk)* (1973), which has a similar storyline except that the son is the one killed and the father takes revenge. Its a *Planet of the Apes* film so it was clearly in the movie-makers’ consciousness.

Notwithstanding, as you say, the story is an archetype - the best known version being Shakespeare’s *[Hamlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamlet)*. Or, for the less-traditionally educated, Disney’s *[The Lion King](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110357/?ref_=ext_shr_lnk)*.